# How do I modify the JSON output for a Result<T,E> serialized with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

A simple code:

```
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    foo: Result<u32, String>
}

fn main() {
    let m = MyStruct {
        foo: Ok(43)
    };
    let n = MyStruct {
        foo: Err("oh no!".into())
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&m).unwrap());
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&n).unwrap());
}
```

This outputs ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f54e11083fef29cbadf2f52eeaa8e82f)):

```
{
  "foo": {
    "Ok": 43
  }
}
{
  "foo": {
    "Err": "oh no!"
  }
}
```

Can I modify the serializer to have a custom output for `Result<T,E>`? I would like something like:

```
// No "Ok" field in case of Ok(T)
{
  "foo": 43
}
// Rename "Err" to "error" in case of Err(E)
{
  "foo": {
    "error": "oh no!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serde [attributes](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) are not powerful enough to do the transformation from the default `Result` serialization to what you want, so you will need to write custom serialization. Fortunately, it is quite simple:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Serializer, ser::SerializeMap};

struct MyStruct {
    foo: Result<u32, String>
}

impl Serialize for MyStruct {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(Some(1))?;
        match &self.foo {
            Ok(value) => map.serialize_entry("foo", &value)?,
            Err(error) => map.serialize_entry("foo", &MyError { error } )?,
        }
        map.end()
    }
}

// This is just used internally to get the nested error field
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct MyError<E> {
    error: E,
}
```